# Exclude A server from list of Output

Tags: powershell

I have a script that reports NTDS service status from entire forest there are few 2003 servers which I want exclude below is the script.

```
$getForest = [system.directoryservices.activedirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest()
$getForest.domains | ForEach-Object {$_.DomainControllers} | ForEach-Object {$_.Name}
```

I was trying something like

```
$getForest = [system.directoryservices.activedirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest()
$getForest.domains | ForEach-Object {$_.DomainControllers} | ForEach-Object {$_.Name} | where-object {$_.name -notlike "server2003.domain.local"}
```

No luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working

```
$exclude = @(
        'dc2.local'
        'dc3.local'
        'dc4.local'                                                                                                                                                                      
        'dc5.local'
    )

    (Get-ADForest).Domains | %{ Get-ADDomainController -Filter * -Server $_ } | Where-Object {$exclude -notcontains $_.hostname} | select Hostname
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second `ForEach-Object` isn't needed, so I've consolidated it into the first.

For this kind of thing I would recommend creating an array of names you want excluded, which I called `$exclude`.

Then I'm using the `-notcontains` operator to check the name against the list from within `Where-Object`.

```
$exclude = @(
    'server2003.domain.local'
    'other2003.domain.local'
)
$getForest = [system.directoryservices.activedirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest()
$getForest.domains | 
    ForEach-Object {$_.DomainControllers.Name} | 
    Where-Object {$exclude -notcontains $_.name}
```